# Exclude objects in queryset based on objects in array

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a queryset

```
<InheritanceQuerySet [<Object(1)>, <Object(2)>, <Object(3)>, <Object(4)>]>
```

and an array with 2 objects that are the same objects as in the queryset

```
arr = [<Object(2)>, <Object(4)>]
```

I'd like to keep the 2 objects that are in the array in the QuerySet and filter all the rest out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [`in` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) with `pk` by using list comprehension on your `arr` to get a list of `pk` values:

```
result = queryset.filter(pk__in=[obj.pk for obj in arr])
```

Comment: Awsome, works like a charm! question, If it was in reverse, should it be like this?```queryset.exclude(pk__in=[obj.pk for obj in arr])```

Comment: @Yorbjörn yes, you can do that.